# What does Flipped() do in Chisel3?

Tags: chisel

I saw a code in section 3.2 interlude in generator-bootcamp:

```
val io = IO(new Bundle {
  val in = Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(8.W)))
  val out = Decoupled(UInt(8.W))
})
```

Is there anyone who know the functionality of "Flipped"?
I searched it in chisel3 doc, but it doesn't have this information.

https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/#Chisel.package$$Flipped$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Decoupled defaults to being an output, that is its argument, in this case the UInt(8.W) will bring data into the module.  Decoupled adds ready and valid handshaking signals to `in`.
The `Flipped()` changes the direction of all fields of it's argument. So `out` is suitable for communicating information out of the module.
The code here is equivalent to

```
val io = IO(new Bundle {
  val in = new Bundle {
    val valid = Input(Bool())
    val ready = Output(Bool())
    val bits  = Input(UInt(8.W))
  }
  val out = new Bundle {
    val valid = Output(Bool())
    val ready = Input(Bool())
    val bits  = Output(UInt(8.W))
  }
}
```

I will see that something gets added to chisel3 wiki.